# Linear operating range of an amplifier as a function of frequency

Tags: amplifier, frequency, linear, saturation

How does the linear operating range of an amplifier (the linear part of the function that describes Power Out vs. Power In), both in theory and in practice, vary with frequency? In other words, if I apply two CW of differing frequencies, will they begin to saturate the amplifier at the same power level or different?

I'm not well versed in the specifics of how an amplifier is made, but am trying to put together a report section to describe at a higher level some of the phenomenon of some RF equipment we are using.

Thanks!

Comment: Which type of amplifier are you talking about.Is it differential Amplifier?.What is the CW of different frequencies.Please tell what is CW,I can't understand the abreviated.

Comment: @Aadarsh : CW = Carrier Wave. (sometimes Continuous Wave, depending on context).

Answer (score 1):

RF amplifiers operating from approximately 200MHz upward begin to obey stranger laws than more rudimentary op-amp circuits. Even below 200MHz, careful consideration should still be given to RF parameters. Normally the frequency response of an amplifier is determined by its transfer function, specifically any inductive / capacitive / resistive elements in its feed forward and feedback paths in addition to its unity gain bandwidth product. In terms of RF, while these general principles still apply, the end solution is not as straight forward.

RF frequency response becomes a combination of any band-limiting reactive components (L's and C's) in addition to the scattering parameters of the active amplifying device. These scattering parameters are very frequency specific and are normally matched for a specific frequency or band of operation. Characterisation of an amplifier outside its intended frequency of operation often results in degraded performance due to power being reflected internally due to an impedance mismatch. Of course this depends on the active device and whether it is broad or narrow band matched. The end result is a measurement called Return Loss, or more simply its analogue Voltage Standing Wave Ratio (VSWR)

Many active devices also specify an IP3 (3rd order intercept) product which allows a designer to estimate any harmonic content while in linear operation. The final transfer function will be heavily dependent on the RF match in addition to any other band limiting components, including stray artifacts such as trace inductance/capacitance. Through incorporation of any expected attenuation due to lumped/SAW/Cavity/strip-line filters, an accurate estimate of output distortion can be made.

More fundamentally, over-driving any amplifier will cause it to clip and introduce harmonic distortion.

So you need to be quite specific in how it is being tested and what is being observed. Generally, the significant majority of RF equipment is narrow band matched which allows for a closer to optimum match for noise figure, or power transfer. The narrower the match bandwidth, the more dynamic the frequency response will be over a broader test range primarily due to reflected input/output power.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin says, the answer may depend on the frequency range you are talking about, but also whether you are talking about broadband or tuned amplifiers - at RF, tuned amplifiers usually offer better performance than broadband by keeping most input and unwanted output signals outside the passband.

And techniques vary at different frequencies.

So you will get better answers from a more specific question, about specific frequencies or frequency bands, and specific signal levels, gains and output powers.

As a rough guide applicable at lower frequencies, you'll find each amplifier has a specified "gain-bandwidth product" - let's say it's 100MHz for your chosen amplifier, usually specified in terms of voltage gain.

That means, if you want a voltage gain of 5 (14dB), the amplifier is restricted to a bandwidth of 100/5 = 20 MHz, and in practice you want some additional margin - say a factor of 2, so you can expect its performance to degrade (additional harmonic and IM distortion) above 10 MHz.